# No results displayed when querying database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli, searchbar

I'm trying to create a searchable database using PHP and MySQL. I have a file called `mission.html` with the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="mission1results.php" id="search">
 <input name="search" type="text"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" vaule="Search"/>
</form>
```

---

mission1results.php

```
<html>
  <body>

<?php
include 'login.php';
$connection = mysqli_connect(
$db_hostname, $db_username,
$db_password, $db_database);

if(mysqli_connect_error()){
die("Database Connection Failed: " .
  mysqli_connect_error() .
  " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
);
}
?>
<?php
$q_cond = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);

$query="SELECT * From Merchant Where MerchantName='".$q_cond."'";

$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);

if ($result===false)
{
    die("Database Query Failed!")
};

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "MerchantName: ".$row["MerchantName"].",";
    echo "<hr/>";
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
?> 
<?php
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

When I hit submit and type in anything in the searchbar nothing appears. I don't get an error, I don't get results, its all blank. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` requires a DB connection. Typo in `vaule="Search"` - `value`, but that won't break anything, but the first one will.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in mission1results.php

```
if ($result===false)
{
    die("Database Query Failed!")
};
```

must be changed for:

```
if ($result===false)
{
    die("Database Query Failed!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` requires a DB connection be passed, then there is your form where you are using a POST method in the form and GET for your query.

Consult the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

```
$q_cond = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['search']);
```

Plus, change

```
if ($result===false)
{
    die("Database Query Failed!")
};
```

to

```
if ($result===false)
{
    die("Database Query Failed!");
}
```

You also have a syntax error `vaule="Search"` change it to `value`

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Also `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to `mysqli_query()` to find any possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead `$_GET['search']` use `$_POST['search']` because your submit forms method is `post`.
2. One of `mysqli_real_escape_string` parameters should be DB connection.
3. syntax errors in HTML, for example, `vaule="Search"`
4. syntax errors in PHP, for example, there shoudn't be `;` after `}` in `if`

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a blank screen with the errors pointed out in previous answers you might want to take a look at the PHP error_reporting level on your system http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php.  You should be seeing PHP errors, on a development server I like to report PHP errors, warnings and notices.

Also, are you expecting users to enter an exact search term?  You might want to consider something like:

```
$query="SELECT * From `Merchant` Where `MerchantName` like '%".$q_cond."%'";
```